# disable devise http authentication, when called with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i am using devise in an application, and when a call is made via ajax, and the user has been signed out due to session expiry, devise shows http authentication... is it possible to make it so that it can send a js to let the caller know that the user is logged out...

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your Devise initializer file

```
config.http_authenticatable = false
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

Comment: My app has both of those set to false but I'm still getting a 401 after making the ajax call to the log in method. Ideas?